# Android: How to reset the RadioButton Id?

Tags: android, radio-button

I add RadioButtons to a RadioGroup programmatically and get the checked RadioButton Id using `getCheckedRadioButtonID()`. If I re-visit the fragment page that has the RadioButtons, the number of RadioButton ID is increased in spite of using removeAllViews() in RadioGroup. It seems `removeAllViews()` removes all child views but it does not reset the RadioButton ID. Is there any way to reset the RadioButtonID?

Comment: Something like this? [RadioGroup # clearcheck()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#clearCheck%28%29). `getCheckedRadioButtonID()` will return `null` after this.

Comment: Thank vikram for the answer. But it also does not reset the RadioButton ID number. It resets the checked status only.

Comment: That's strange. Documentation says: `Clears the selection. When the selection is cleared, no radio button in this group is selected and getCheckedRadioButtonId() returns null.`

Comment: Yes. The documentation is correct. It returns null. As you know, each RadioButton has its own ID number like 1, 2, 3,... I expected that the ID number might reset after using removeAllViews(). But it does not and it keep increases like 4, 5, 6.... It seems Android assigns a new ID until the life cycle of the interface is finish. Anyway thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

A hacky kind of fix but you can use a modulo that sets the ID based on the multiple of the number of radio buttons you have. For example if you have four radio buttons in your group

```
    int radioValueBottom = mBottomRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioValueBottom = radioValueBottom % 4;
```

this will give you the same value no matter how many times you refresh or leave the page.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the id and don't let it be by default. If you use a for cycle, just do something like this:

rb.setId(i);